# Zip line simulation with Blender physics

Tags: animation

Is there a way to simulate a zip-lining motion using the Blender physics engine?

I am new to Blender physics.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using physics for this. Zip lining is a pretty tough one for blender, as the program isn't optimized for physics simulation. Keep in mind that it has to calculate friction of the wheels on the cable, the wheels should be high poly, otherwise they'll run off the line, the line has to stretch and sag in etc. These are very complex physics. I suggest trying to use curves and animate the line that way and using the same curve to make the wheels follow the line. Good luck!

Comment: My first thought is to have the handle [follow a path](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/properties/data.html#curve-path-animation) and use [rigid body hinge](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/constraints/types/hidge.html) to have a person swinging with it as it moves.